# How do I add multiple series to a Razor Helper Chart?

Tags: charts, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart goes over how to create simple charts and they are working, but I can't seem to figure out how to add two data series (from two separate DB queries) to the same chart.

Comment: It would help if you could post the code you have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried calling the `AddSeries()` method twice, once for each database?

Comment: Ok. I give. I'm unclear how to get the column I need from the collection. 

xValue: db.Query(querystring) (then what?)

Comment: This answer is correct. For the record, the code I ended up using looked like this: 

        `.AddSeries(
            xValue: SubmissionData.Select(d => d["ddate"] as string).ToList(),
            yValues: SubmissionData.Select(d => d["ccnt"] as int?).ToList())
          .AddSeries(
            xValue: ApproveData.Select(d => d["ddate2"] as string).ToList(),
            yValues: ApproveData.Select(d => d["ccnt2"] as int?).ToList())`